# h:outputScript causes IndexOutOfBoundsException in Primefaces page

Tags: primefaces, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using Primefaces 4.0 in my project.
When i use  h:outputScript in template file, getting javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id j_idt54.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:.

And remove the outputScipt tag from template, everythink is ok.

```
<h:outputScript library="script"  name="/resources/script/generalScript.js"></h:outputScript>       

</h:body>
```

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{view.login}"
                styleClass="user-buttonLvl2" >
            </p:commandButton>
```

And the printStackTrace is that:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id j_idt54.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$1.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1589)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.VisitUtils.doFullNonIteratingVisit(VisitUtils.java:75)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:257)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:181)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:448)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:187)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:111)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
```

Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: read this: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-jsf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using **library="script"** tag then give path from `script` folder in name tag.

Like this : **name="generalScript.js"**

The name tag itself add the full path of scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Before i add this question here, first usage is like this. <h:outputScript library="script"  name="generalScript.js">. And the generalScript.js file is in /resources/script/generalScript.js. My components can found it but this error cause after action of the commandButton.

Comment: try putting your javascripts inline (same *.xhtml page) and see if the error is continue it may problem of java scripts. and try to debug your java scripts. Or can you share full page with bean. it may help to found out the problem.